# How to include the file name on the output of this command?

Tags: awk

How to include the file name on the output of this command?

```
tail -n 1 *.txt |awk -F "|" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi Cyrus,

the above commands output my desired result but I also needed the file name for the output. basically at the last line of a file there was a result print $2 is the output needed and delimited by pipe. I just wanted the output to also include the file name. thanks

Comment: `awk` cannot know the original filename, because it is reading a single pipe stream. All the lines received from there will have the same filename `-`, signifying `stdin`.

Comment: Regarding `the above commands output my desired result` - that's fine but if you don't show us sample input and expected output then we can't suggest an alternative that has the same behavior as we don't know what that behavior is. For example if there's 1 file matches *.txt vs multiple then different version of tail will do different things, and we don't know if a file is empty if you expect no output or just a FILENAME or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This requires GNU Awk:

```bash
awk -F "|" 'ENDFILE{print $2, FILENAME}' *.txt
```

P.S. You really should add an example of your desired output, not just describe it in a comment.

Comment: thank you it worked. still trying to learn.

Comment: Note that `gawk` (contrary to `tail`) will read the files in full in that case.

Comment: Note that for those files whose name ends in `.txt` that are empty, you'll end up printing the second field of the last line of the last processed file that was not empty.

Comment: Note that it assumes file names don't contain `=` characters. Using `./*.txt` instead of `*.txt` and use `substr(FILENAME, 3)` instead of `FILENAME` would work around that.

Comment: Huh, never knew about the `=` behavior. Thanks, TIL.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in any case [standard `tail`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/tail.html) only supports up to one filename as argument.

Some do accept more than one filename argument but the output varies from implementation to implementation and is generally impossible to post-process reliably.

Here, with a Korn-like/POSIX shell, you could do:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  tail -n1 < "$file" | {
    IFS='|' read -r ignore value ignore && printf '%s\n' "$file: $value"
  }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use autodie qw(open);

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {

  # Simple implementation of `tail -1`:
  # Seek to somewhere near the end of the file and
  # begin reading lines until we're at eof.  Then
  # extract and print the 2nd field along with the
  # filename.

  my $size = -s $f;
  my $seek = int($size / 20);   # start with 1/20th of file size
  $seek = 500  if $seek < 500;  # min 500 bytes
  $seek = 5000 if $seek > 5000; # max 5000

  open(my $fh,'<',$f);
  seek($fh, -$seek, 2);

  while (<$fh>) {
    if (eof) {
      chomp;
      my @fields = split /\|/;
      printf "%s: %s\n", $f, $fields[1];
    }
  };
  close($fh);
};
```

Save as, e.g. `./tail1-col2.pl`, make executable with `chmod +x ./tail1-col2.pl` and run as:

```
./tail1-col2.pl *.txt
```